Pasting MathML equations generated by KaTeX into Word
When trying to paste Math equations from a KaTeX generated equation on the web to Microsoft Word 365, the whole equations gets correctly converted, but if there are Large Operators like Σ, word will show a placeholder next to it and then the indexed variable, instead of just showing the indexed variable inside the placeholder.

What i get when copying a KaTeX equation from the web:
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block"><semantics><mrow><munderover><mo>∑</mo><mrow><mi>i</mi><mo>=</mo><mn>1</mn></mrow><mi>N</mi></munderover><mrow><mo stretchy="false">(</mo><msup><mo stretchy="false">)</mo><mn>2</mn></msup><msub><mi>u</mi><mi>i</mi></msub></mrow><mo>=</mo><munderover><mo>∑</mo><mrow><mi>i</mi><mo>=</mo><mn>1</mn></mrow><mi>N</mi></munderover><mo stretchy="false">(</mo><msub><mi>Y</mi><mi>i</mi></msub><mo>−</mo><msub><mover accent="true"><mi>Y</mi><mo>^</mo></mover><mi>i</mi></msub><msup><mo stretchy="false">)</mo><mn>2</mn></msup><mo>=</mo><munderover><mo>∑</mo><mrow><mi>i</mi><mo>=</mo><mn>1</mn></mrow><mi>N</mi></munderover><mo stretchy="false">(</mo><msub><mi>Y</mi><mi>i</mi></msub><mo>−</mo><msub><mi>β</mi><mn>0</mn></msub><mo>−</mo><msub><mi>β</mi><mn>1</mn></msub><msub><mi>X</mi><mi>i</mi></msub><msup><mo stretchy="false">)</mo><mn>2</mn></msup></mrow><annotation encoding="application/x-tex">\sum_{i=1}^N (u_i)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^N (Y_i - \hat{Y}_i)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^N (Y_i - \beta_0 - \beta_1 X_i)^2</annotation></semantics></math>

What i should have based on Word:
<mml:math xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math"><mml:mrow><mml:munderover><mml:mo stretchy="true">∑</mml:mo><mml:mrow><mml:mi>i</mml:mi><mml:mo>=</mml:mo><mml:mn>1</mml:mn></mml:mrow><mml:mrow><mml:mi>N</mml:mi></mml:mrow></mml:munderover><mml:mrow><mml:mo>(</mml:mo><mml:msub><mml:mrow><mml:mi>u</mml:mi></mml:mrow><mml:mrow><mml:mi>i</mml:mi></mml:mrow></mml:msub><mml:msup><mml:mrow><mml:mo>)</mml:mo></mml:mrow><mml:mrow><mml:mn>2</mml:mn></mml:mrow></mml:msup></mml:mrow></mml:mrow><mml:mo>=</mml:mo><mml:mrow><mml:munderover><mml:mo stretchy="true">∑</mml:mo><mml:mrow><mml:mi>i</mml:mi><mml:mo>=</mml:mo><mml:mn>1</mml:mn></mml:mrow><mml:mrow><mml:mi>N</mml:mi></mml:mrow></mml:munderover><mml:mrow><mml:mo>(</mml:mo><mml:msub><mml:mrow><mml:mi>Y</mml:mi></mml:mrow><mml:mrow><mml:mi>i</mml:mi></mml:mrow></mml:msub><mml:mo>-</mml:mo><mml:msub><mml:mrow><mml:mover accent="true"><mml:mrow><mml:mi>Y</mml:mi></mml:mrow><mml:mo>^</mml:mo></mml:mover></mml:mrow><mml:mrow><mml:mi>i</mml:mi></mml:mrow></mml:msub><mml:msup><mml:mrow><mml:mo>)</mml:mo></mml:mrow><mml:mrow><mml:mn>2</mml:mn></mml:mrow></mml:msup></mml:mrow></mml:mrow><mml:mo>=</mml:mo><mml:mrow><mml:munderover><mml:mo stretchy="true">∑</mml:mo><mml:mrow><mml:mi>i</mml:mi><mml:mo>=</mml:mo><mml:mn>1</mml:mn></mml:mrow><mml:mrow><mml:mi>N</mml:mi></mml:mrow></mml:munderover><mml:mrow><mml:mo>(</mml:mo><mml:msub><mml:mrow><mml:mi>Y</mml:mi></mml:mrow><mml:mrow><mml:mi>i</mml:mi></mml:mrow></mml:msub><mml:mo>-</mml:mo><mml:msub><mml:mrow><mml:mi>β</mml:mi></mml:mrow><mml:mrow><mml:mn>0</mml:mn></mml:mrow></mml:msub><mml:mo>-</mml:mo><mml:msub><mml:mrow><mml:mi>β</mml:mi></mml:mrow><mml:mrow><mml:mn>1</mml:mn></mml:mrow></mml:msub><mml:msub><mml:mrow><mml:mi>X</mml:mi></mml:mrow><mml:mrow><mml:mi>i</mml:mi></mml:mrow></mml:msub><mml:msup><mml:mrow><mml:mo>)</mml:mo></mml:mrow><mml:mrow><mml:mn>2</mml:mn></mml:mrow></mml:msup></mml:mrow></mml:mrow></mml:math>

That said, i actually figured out that by just inserting a  that comprehends the indexed variable, the issue is fixed. I don't know how i could implement such a parsing with so many possible cases into a code that fixes the issue for me.
I tried to manually fix this by writing the  element before and after each iterable variable, but i would like to write some code that does it automatically.
